# PowerBI Date column - 1 year with static date

Tags: powerbi, dax

My fiscal year start is in the past. I have a date column and I have the code below in a separate calculated column.

```
Year Start = DATE(YEAR(sales[close_date].[Year])-1,MONTH(12),DAY(22))
```

On the first row as an example, I have 31/07/2016 but in this column I am getting 21/01/1904

Could someone explain why?

Comment: You should update your questions with sample data and provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You can check this below code-

```
Year Start = DATE(sales[close_date].[Year] -1, 12,22)
```